# angular formio pages as a grid

Tags: angular, formio

I am implementing angular formio drag and drop functionality, as part of that I have implemented from builder.

In form Builder what ever the screen created I will save in the DB and retrieve and show using form render.

here my concern is I want to show all the pages created using form builder, I want to show them in one page as a grids, when ever I click on a particular grid that particular page should open.

For this how can I create a grid.